# how to insert part of model properties in mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i have a table that has 12 fields, all allow null except the Id field(Primary Key), i am using database first workflow of mvc 5, in my model annotation all 12 fields are required, i am  displaying only four fields in one views and the rest in another view, but while trying to insert values into the table from the view that has four fields, it reports error that there are other fields that are required, how do i insert only these four fields, with removing required annotation from the rest? Here is my code:

```
 public ActionResult Estate(Customer cus)
    {
        try
        {
            var customer = new Customer
            {
                ClientId = cus.ClientId,
                ClientGroup = cus.ClientGroup,
                OrgName = cus.OrgName,
                Branch = cus.Branch

            };

            db.Customers.Add(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

           ModelState.AddModelError("",ex.Message);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: show `Customer` definition

Comment: Are you creating a customer here?  If the fields are required then you need to populate them with something - can you use some default values?

Comment: If the columns are nullable and the form spans multiple requests, guess what?  The fields *aren't* required.  So remove the "required" from your model annotation.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a viewmodel. One viewmodel for each view, each containing only the properties required to display in that view. Passing `Customer` to a view that only needs to deal with a subset of it's required properties is a bad idea.

Comment: Chances are that the UI would be easier to understand with all the required fields on one screen as well (using a wizard, modal, or whatever).

Comment: @Jason Evans, the table customer has two types of customers: individual and Corporate, i was asked to use one table, otherwise i would have created two tables for each, let me try and research how to use view model, but if you can give a link, i will appreciate.

Comment: @MarkpSmith, the user wants to be seeing normal database table null while viewing the record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, a viewmodel might make things easier for you. Here is some example code.

Pretend I have a `Person` class, which is from Entity Framework

```
public class Person
{
    [Required]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string RandomStuff { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a view that asks the user for a new `firstname` value. Here's what I'd do - create a viewmodel class that will be associated with the view (.cshtml) file:

```
public class HomeIndexViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
}
```

The viewmodel contains only the properties that the view needs to care about. Then in the controller I can do:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new HomeIndexViewModel();

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

The view could be something like:

@model WebApplication1.Controllers.HomeIndexViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Firstname)
}
```

Then when you post the data back to the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HomeIndexViewModel viewModel)
{
    var person = new Person() { Firstname = viewModel.Firstname };

    // blah....
}
```

when you post data back, you will not encounter validation errors caused by the property `RandomStuff` being empty, because the viewmodel does not care about that property. The viewmodel contains only the data that is required by the view, no more than that.
This is something I do all the time.